# Fast circuit breaker on low side of mosfet driven led circuit

Tags: led-driver, short-circuit, fuses

[image]I have some high power CREE COB LED's CXA1304-0000-000C00A20E8, which I turn on for 0.5 ms using a MOSFET on the low side. The signal comes from an optocoupler.
I experienced some burned MOSFETs from shorts in the LED circuit. I am looking for a short circuit breaker, which I could add next to the MOSFET.
So far I checked the datasheet of TI's eFuses but they are to slow in building up the target voltage(23.9V/1.6ms)
In the best case the LED's circuit will stay open if 2 Amps get exceeded until reset. A fault indicator pin would be nice also.

Edit: R1 (Voltage drop around 9V) is allocated in the lamp, not next to the MOSFET. Nominal current is about 1A. The rise time should be less than 10 µs. The shorts arise from imperfections during build/install/use. For example all LEDs are shorted.

Comment: *I experienced some burned MOSFETs from shorts in the LED circuit.* Explain what happens **exactly**, are one or more LEDs shorted? You can probably only solve that by using a **constant current driver** to drive the LEDs.

Comment: What is the usual drop across R1? Can you use that voltage to sense and limit the current? Provide us with some more specs on required rise time, nominal current, etc.

Comment: "Shorts in the LED circuit" would imply one or more shorted/defective LED's, which would require a repair anyway. In that case you could just use a regular fuse.

Comment: in the case of a major short circuit, the average fuse will still be thinking about blowing when the mosfet has gone up in smoke. You want some means of current limit for your mosfet. A transistor and a sense resistor should suffice.

Comment: @Kartman That 10 ohm is still there. An appropiate fuse with that 10 ohm in place should be doable.

Comment: @Unimportant - true. The mosfet should hang in there long enough.

Answer (score 1):

10 ohm seems far to large for “high power LEDs”.

If you need accidental short circuit protection, then a constant current regulator should be used with a crowbar or fold back on voltage sensing. PTC fuses that can heat up to limit current and so must be faster than the target being protected.

Comment: is looking for self protected low side switches like https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/BSP75G.pdf or NCV8402 a dead end?

Comment: No but details specs on relevant circuit specs are a dead-end

Comment: I will give ZXMS6005DG self protecting mosfet a try. I hope this will make this simple and flexible design more robust for some failure cases.

Comment: Your schematic shows the root part number and not the letter which indicates the number series elements each about 3V @ 0.1A thus C is 3S is 9V and 4 such devices in series makes it 12S or 36V . The Rs of each array depends on  the incremental slope of Vf/If which causes the rise in voltage of about 10% to a reasonable power dissipation. Thus the Rs for 3S has more P diodes on chip than the F (6th letter of alphabet) being 18V will have fewer parallel strings on chip and thus have a greater Rs of each chip.  In any case., a low RdsOn switch alone is a poor solution.

Comment: Please use or design a regulator for the peak current limit and modulation this with PWM for dimming.